# OracleRefCursor C# ODP.net, enumeration yielded no results

Tags: c#, database, oracle, stored-procedures, odp.net

Below is the code I am using to connect to a database to run a stored procedure. Everything seems to be working fine except the cursor is not returning any results. I know the procedure works because it is already being used in a report.

```
            using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(DB_CONNECTION))
        {
            conn.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("package.ClockProcedure", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("arg_year", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = year;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("arg_month", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = month;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("arg_pay_type", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = payType;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("arg_before_value", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = beforeValue;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("arg_after_value", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = afterValue;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("arg_results", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);

            DataSet dt = new DataSet();
            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);

            conn.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
            return dt;
        }
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to run `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`, Procedure is executed automatically at `da.Fill(dt);`.

Comment: Does the working report use the same Oracle user as your application?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yes it does.

Comment: Bind by position is default so unless you have turned that on elsewhere, make sure your parameters are added in the proper order. If that isn't the issue, it may be helpful to include the sproc definition in your question.